# Find quoted strings and replace content between double quotes

Tags: c#, regex, escaping, double-quotes, regexp-replace

I have a `string`, e.g.

```
"24.09.2019","545","878","5"
```

that should be processed to

```
"{1}","{2}","{3}","{4}"
```

Now I am trying to use *regular expression*:

```
string replacementString="{NG}";
Regex regex = new Regex("\\\"[0-9\.]+\\\"");    
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(originalString);

List<string> replacements = new List<string>();

for (int x = 0; x < matches.Count; x++)    
{    
    string replacement = String.Copy(replacementString);    
    replacement = replacement.Replace("NG", (x + 1).ToString());    
    replacements.Add(replacement);
    Match match = matches[x];
}

replacements.Reverse();

int cnt = 0;    

foreach (var match in matches.Cast<Match>().Reverse())    
{    
    originalStringTmp = originalStringTmp.Replace(
        match.Index, 
        match.Length, 
        replacements[cnt]);    

    cnt++;    
}
```

And

```
public static string Replace(this string s, int index, int length, string replacement)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.Append(s.Substring(0, index));
    builder.Append(replacement);
    builder.Append(s.Substring(index + length));

    return builder.ToString();
 }
```

But in this case the result is

```
{1},{2},{3},{4}
```

What regular expression should I use instead of

```
\"[0-9\.]+\"
```

to achieve the result

```
"{1}","{2}","{3}","{4}"
```

with C# regular expression?

Comment: Is that string a piece of CSV or JSON?

Comment: No, it is not. Such strings in a huge file, each string at line in file. So, in this case it's just a C# (raw) string.

Comment: You may wish to present a few lines from the file to avoid false positives.

Comment: In this case I am talking about and working on just one string... So, it's just a string, as in my question :).

Comment: Can you be more clear on your question, at least for me wasn't totally clear? You want to parse a line of text with: "24.09.2019","545","878","5" and output what? this: "{1}","{2}","{3}","{4}" ? if you have more numbers you continue with {5} and so on... ?

Comment: following @user1845593 comment. Is the content between the double quotes always numerical with `.` somewhere? Could you please specify how your data _can_ look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `Regex.Replace` in order to replace all the quotations (I've assumed that quotation is *escaped* by itself: `"abc""def" -> abc"def`) within the string:

```
  string source = "\"24.09.2019\",\"545\",\"878\",\"5\"";

  int index = 0;

  string result = Regex.Replace(source, "\"([^\"]|\"\")*\"", m => $"\"{{{++index}}}\"");
```

**Demo:**

```
  Func<string, string> convert = (source => {
    int index = 0;

    return Regex.Replace(source, "\"([^\"]|\"\")*\"", m => $"\"{{{++index}}}\"");
  });

  String[] tests = new string[] {
    "abc",
    "\"abc\", \"def\"\"fg\"",
    "\"\"",
    "\"24.09.2019\",\"545\",\"878\",\"5\"",
    "name is \"my name\"; value is \"78\"\"\"\"\"",
    "empty: \"\" and not empty: \"\"\"\""
  };

  string demo = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,-50} -> {convert(test)}"));

  Console.Write(demo);
```

**Outcome:**

```
abc                                                -> abc
"abc", "def""fg"                                   -> "{1}", "{2}"
""                                                 -> "{1}"
"24.09.2019","545","878","5"                       -> "{1}","{2}","{3}","{4}"
name is "my name"; value is "78"""""               -> name is "{1}"; value is "{2}"
empty: "" and not empty: """"                      -> empty: "{1}" and not empty: "{2}"
```

**Edit:** You can easily elaborate the replacement, e.g. if you want to replace integer numbers only

```
  Func<string, string> convert = (source => {
    int index = 0;

    // we have match "m" with index "index"
    // out task is to provide a string which will be put instead of match
    return Regex.Replace(
      source, 
     "\"([^\"]|\"\")*\"", 
      m => int.TryParse(m.Value.Trim('"'), out int _drop)
        ? $"\"{{{++index}}}\"") // if match is a valid integer, replace it
        : m.Value);             // if not, keep intact 
  });
```

In general case

```
  Func<string, string> convert = (source => {
    int index = 0;

    // we have match "m" with index "index"
    // out task is to provide a string which will be put instead of match
    return Regex.Replace(
      source, 
     "\"([^\"]|\"\")*\"", 
      m => {
        // now we have a match "m", with its value "m.Value"
        // its index "index" 
        // and we have to return a string which will be put instead of match

        // if you want unquoted value, i.e. abc"def instead of "abc""def"
        // string unquoted = Regex.Replace(
        //   m.Value, "\"+", match => new string('"', match.Value.Length / 2)); 

        return //TODO: put the relevant code here
      }
  });
```

Comment: Dmitry, is it possible to extract double quotes with regexp and not to hardcode them in ` m => $"\"{{{++index}}}\"")`? I am working on a regexp replacer application, where I have 4 rich text boxes. The first one for regexp to find. So, regexp will be dynamical, user allowed to change that field. Second rtb is replacement string. If it contains NG, group number will be places instead NG. Third rtb has some text is highlighted preview of regexp. Fourth rtb - is text from third rtb with replaced by regexp from first rtb with text from second rtb. So, I can't hardcode double quotes in result.

Comment: @Arthur: sure, all you have to do is to change the *lambda* `m => ...` you have `Match` `m` (e.g `"24.09.2019"`) and its `index` (e.g. `0`) and you should return a string (may be based on rtb) which should be put instead of the match. In my code I put `"\"" + (++index).ToString() + "\""` instead of every match, but you can implement any other lambda.

Comment: OK, I understand your lambda, but it has hard-coded value "\"". My question is how to make regexp that will extract, for example, `"123"` and `"5"` from `"123", "5"`, and `123` and `5` from `"123"` and `"5"`, after that is and will replace them with group numbers. Input regexp and input string could be any. So that's why ` m => $"\"{{{++index}}}\""` with hard coded \" is not good solution for my case.

Comment: @Arthur: if you don't want `\"` you can drop it from lambda `m => $"{{{++index}}}"` and have `{1},{2},{3},{4}` instead of `"{1}","{2}","{3}","{4}"`. If you want to remove quotations from match `m` (`m.Value == "abc""def"` but you want `abc"def`) you can try `string quotationRemoved = Regex.Replace(m.Value, "\"+", match => new string('"', match.Value.Length / 2));`

Comment: May I speak Russian? )))

Comment: @Arthur: sure, you can. Probably in a chat room?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199916/discussion-between-arthur-and-dmitry-bychenko).

Answer (score 0):

```
string originalString = "\"24.09.2019\",\"545\",\"878\",\"5\"";
var regex = new Regex("\"[0-9\\.]+\"");
var matches = regex.Matches(originalString);

string result = string.Join(',', Enumerable.Range(1, matches.Count).Select(n => $"\"{{{n}}}\""));
```

**Input:**

> "24.09.2019","545","878","5"

**Result:**

> "{1}","{2}","{3}","{4}"

Comment: interesting solution, but I stucked on other moment. The string is not static and they are not alway contains commas. So, `string.Join(',', ` will not work for all strings...

Comment: The regex doesn't match "," the "," is to build the final string! the regex will only match "[0-9].+", in other words numbers or dots inside double quotes